# Using IF Within php While Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

i have this code below it is the loop for get popular posts in wordpress

```
$First_Img = '<img src="'.YPE_Catch_First_Image().'">';
while ( $popular->have_posts() ) : $popular->the_post();
    $html  = '<article>';
    $html .= '<section class="bootstrap-nav-thumb">';
    $html .= '<p>';
    $html .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
    $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
    $html .= '</a>';
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '</section>';

    $html .= '<aside class="bootstrap-title-info">';
    $html .= '<p>';
    $html .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '<p class="text-muted">' . get_the_date() . '||'. getPostViews(get_the_ID()) . '</p>';
    $html .= '</aside>';
    $html .= '</article>';
    echo $html;
endwhile;
```

i want use this code

```
html .= if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
} else {
    echo $First_Img;
};
```

instead of this code

```
$html .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
```

but the server show the error `unexpected 'if' (T-IF)` please help me how i can use the conditional statement when i has post thumbnail print it and if don't has post thumbnail print the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect:

```
$html .= if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
} else {
    echo $First_Img;
};
```

Correct:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    $html .=  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
} else {
    $html .=  $First_Img;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
} else {
    $html .= $First_Img;
};
```

The `.=` operator essentially means "append to". The line of code you originally had meant "append whatever `get_the_post_thumbnail(...)` returns to `$html`".

This way, you check your condition with the `if` statement, and append what you want.

Comment: `html` should be `$html`

Answer (score 1):

Try a [ternary operator](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4):

```
   $html .= has_post_thumbnail() ?  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive')) : $First_Img;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
  $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
} else {
  $html .= $First_Img;
};
```

Comment: `html` should be `$html`